# Understant with variables in some clases Slick2d

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm a student and i'm trying to do a game in Java with Slick2D, but i have a problem that i dont understand. I have some clases and from some i can get variables but in some i cant, and it all seems the same.

For example i have the class Gameplay where all gamelogic and render takes place:

```
public class Gameplay extends BasicGameState {


private GeneradorNiveles gen;

private ComprobadorColisiones comp;


private Player p;

private Bullet[] bAr;
private int bArpos;
private Bullet bala;
private boolean bActiva = false;
private int curBul = 0; 
private int MAXBALAS =50;

private Rectangle[] eRect;

private Rectangulo r;



private Input input;

private Random rnd;

private Enemy[] eAr;
private Enemy en;
private int eArpos;
private float curVel, curX;
private int MAXENE = 5;

private Image fondo;
private String ref = "res/fondo.png";


public Gameplay(){



}



@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
        throws SlickException {

    comp = new ComprobadorColisiones();
    r = new Rectangulo();
    gen = new GeneradorNiveles();

    gen.init(gc);

    eRect = new Rectangle[MAXBALAS];


    rnd = new Random();

    p = new Player(300,500);


    fondo = new Image(ref);

    eAr = new Enemy[MAXENE];
    en = new Enemy();
    curVel= rnd.nextFloat();

    bAr =  new Bullet[MAXBALAS];

    bala = new Bullet();

    // Llena el array de eAr con enemigos//
    crearNuevosEnemigosY0();
    //

    //Llena el array b con las balas//
    llenarArrayBalas();
    //



}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {



    input = gc.getInput();

    fondo.draw(0, 0); // Dibujamos el fondo//

    p.render(gc, g); // Ejecuta el render del player //


    //For que carga todos los render de todas las balas
    for(Bullet bu : bAr){

        bu.render(gc, g);

        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_SPACE)){

            bArpos = bu.getPos();


            bAr[curBul] = new Bullet(bala.getX(), bala.getY());

            curBul +=1;

            if(curBul >=MAXBALAS){

                curBul = 0;                 
            }



            if(bu.getY()<0){

                bAr[bArpos] = new Bullet(bala.getX(), bala.getY());
            }

        }




    }



    //For que carga todos los renders de todos los enemigos del array//
    for(Enemy en : eAr){

        en.render(gc, g);



        //If que comprueba si llega al final y crea otros nuevos
        if(en.getY()>600){

            eArpos = en.getPos();





            crearNuevoEnemigoMuerto(eArpos);


            //crearNuevosEnemigos();


        }


    }








}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
        throws SlickException {



    comp.doy();

    p.update(gc, delta); // Ejecuta el update del player//

    //For donde hace el update de todas las balas del Array
    for(Bullet bu : bAr){

        bu.update(gc, delta);

    }



    input = gc.getInput();

    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){


        Main.app.exit();




    }
    //Envia el valor de la x de la bala a la x de la b
    else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){

        bala.setX(p.getX()+20);
        bala.setY(p.getY());

        comp.setxEn(en.getX());




    }
    //

        //For donde hace el update de todos los enemigos de la Array
        for(Enemy en : eAr){

            try {
                en.update(gc, delta);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            };

        }





}




public void crearNuevosEnemigosY0(){

for (int i = 0; i < eAr.length; i++) {

    curVel= rnd.nextFloat();

    while(curVel>0.2f || curVel<0.1f){

        curVel= rnd.nextFloat();

    }

    eAr[i] = new Enemy(20+i*5, 0, i, curVel);


    }   

}

public void crearNuevoEnemigoMuerto(int eApos){


    curVel = rnd.nextFloat();
    curX = eApos*50/rnd.nextFloat();



    while(curVel>0.4f || curVel<0.1f){

        curVel= rnd.nextFloat();


    }

    while(curX<50 || curX>395){

        curX = rnd.nextInt(395);

    }





    eAr[eApos] = new Enemy(curX, 0, eApos, curVel);


}


public void llenarArrayBalas(){

    for (int i = 0; i < bAr.length; i++) {

        bAr[i] = new Bullet(i);

    }


}




@Override
public int getID() {

    return 0;
}

public int geteArpos() {
    return eArpos;
}

public void seteArpos(int eArpos) {
    this.eArpos = eArpos;
}
```

}

And those two:

Player class:

```
public class Player {

private Image pImg;
private String ref = "res/player.jpg";
private  float x,y;

private Bullet b;   

private int limite = 430;

private Input input;

private float vel = 0.5f;



boolean shoot = false;

public Player(){


}
public Player(float x, float y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;


}


public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {

//  b = new Bullet();

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    //pImg.draw(x,y);

    g.drawImage(new Image(ref), x, y);



    g.drawString(String.valueOf(x), 20, 30);




}


public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {

    input = gc.getInput();

    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){

        if(x>0){

            x -= vel * delta;
        }

    }else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){

        if(x<limite){
            x += vel * delta;
        }
    }





}

public Input returnImput(){
    return input;


}

public boolean isShoot() {
    return shoot;
}
public void setShoot(boolean shoot) {
    this.shoot = shoot;
}
public float getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public float getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public float getVel() {
    return vel;
}
public void setVel(float vel) {
    this.vel = vel;
}
```

}

Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy  {

private GeneradorNiveles gen;

private Gameplay gp;


private float x, y;
private int pos;

private int eArpos;

private float vel = 0.5f;
private float velH = 0.2f;

private int valor = 1, contador ;

private String ref = "res/sE1.png";

private int aux;


private Rectangle eRect;

public Enemy(){



}

public Enemy(int eArpos){

    this.eArpos = eArpos;
}


public Enemy(float x, float y, int pos, float vel){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.vel = vel;

}



public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {

    gp = new Gameplay();

    gen = new GeneradorNiveles();

}


public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {



    g.drawImage(new Image(ref), x , y);
    //g.draw(eRect = new Rectangle(x,y,20,20));






}




public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException, InterruptedException {



    animacionEnemigo(delta);




    //System.out.println(eArpos);


}


public void animacionEnemigo(int delta){

            contador += delta;

        switch(valor){

        case 1:
            x -= velH * delta;

            if((x)<50){
                contador = 6000;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            x += velH * delta;

            if((int)x>395){
                contador = 6000;
            }

            break;



        }



        y += vel * delta; // Velocidad//

        if(contador>5000){


            contador = 0;


            if(valor == 1){

                valor = 2;
            }else if(valor == 2){

                valor = 1;
            }
        }

    pasarVar(); 


}

public void pasarVar(){



}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public Rectangle geteRect() {
    return eRect;
}

public void seteRect(Rectangle eRect) {
    this.eRect = eRect;
}
```

So i can get in other class the variables from player and not from enemy and i dont know what is wrong. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: What variable are you trying to get?

Comment: The float x and float y from enemy. In Gameplay i do that:

     bala.setX(p.getX()+20);
        bala.setY(p.getY());

        comp.setxEn(en.getX());

With player (p.getX()) it works but with enemy (en.getX()) didnt work.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace? How the exception looks like?

Comment: I dont have a stacktrace. It doesnt display a exception, simply it sends 0.0, i mean when i do en.getX() the result is 0.0.

Comment: It means that x variable is initialized with default value which is 0.0 and then you don't change it. Maybe you miss setX method somewhere.

Comment: All setX methods are set, just it doesent send they value.